# Mysql subqueries optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization

I would like to know how can i make this type of query faster.Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT * FROM

(
  SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN 'someDate' AND 'someDate' 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN 'someDate' AND 'someDate' 
)as unitable
```

Comment: By adding proper indexes to your tables

Comment: I have ID index on the tables.

Comment: it depends on {condition}, but basically you have to create indexes

Comment: When i execute the queries seperate it happens for 1 second.When they are in this union it takes 30 seconds.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` will explain to you what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, rewrite your query without a subquery.  Second, change the date comparisons so you are not using any functions on the date columns (functions on the constants are fine).  Third, add an index on the date column:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_table1_date on table1(date);
CREATE INDEX idx_table2_date on table2(date);

SELECT * 
ROM table1
WHERE date BETWEEN 'someDate' AND 'someDate' 
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM table2
WHERE date BETWEEN 'someDate' AND 'someDate' ;
```